# What’s a word for someone who does not believe in sexual orientation?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, gender-politics, interpersonal-relations

What do you call a person who does not believe in sexual orientation (other than the word *bisexual*)?

Comment: An *asexual* has no sexual orientation. But what do you mean *"doesn't believe in sexual orientation"*? They think all humans are really bisexual and do not have a gender preference?

Comment: I would call such a person an agnostic.  (And I suppose I'd have to refer to the person as "it".)

Comment: _Bisexual_ does not mean a person who does not believe in sexual orientation. Are you sure about what you are trying to ask? Please give more details and include your research if possible.

Comment: I see terms like _nongenderist_, _antigenderist_ and _gender atheist_ but they are not well-recognized terms. There is a similar question asked and answered on [goaskalice.columbia.edu](http://goaskalice.columbia.edu/bi-gay-pansexual-what-do-i-call-myself) also.

Comment: _Strange_ would be the word I would use. Sexual orientation is a scientifically proven aspect of all animals, and not believing in it would be akin to not believing in taste buds or thirst. It would make no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You’re right that as posed, this is a confusing question. Even someone whose tastes in wines varies wildly according to the intersection of corn futures, mad-cow scares, the phase of the moon, the Atlantic Multidecadal Oscillation, and the price of tea in China still “believes” in taste buds. The question is too brief as currently worded to know quite what the OP really means or wants to know here.

Answer (score 0):

She/He is a [pansexual](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pansexual); not limited in sexual choice with regard to biological sex, gender, or gender identity.

Comment: And here I thought it was randy bonobos who were **pan**sexuals: *Pan paniscus*. :)

Comment: Pansexuality is an attraction orientation, not a gender-identification per se, unless people are misappropriating it. Which happens...

Comment: pangendered then ?

Comment: @medica But I **think** that’s what the OP is asking about.  I’m not perfectly certain, however.

Comment: Hmm. Apologies then. I don't know why I interpreted this so differently.

Comment: @medica - because it's difficult to know what the OP intends by the terms employed.

Answer (score 0):

Asexuals are people who have no sexual desire, not people who have no gender.

People who deny having a gender are quite rare (people normally exist on a continuum, and it's not uncommon to identify as partially both).

People who don't like the idea of gender (which is what you seem to be asking) are just trying to change language and philosophy. Or they are delusional.

Ignore it (well, except maybe in their presence?)

Comment: I get the idea that the OP is referring not to people’s own sexual self-identities as male or female, but rather to their attraction orientation towards other people. But there’s a lot of wiggle-room in that domain, and without further clarification from the OP, I wouldn’t want to say for sure. But that’s the simplest reading of their question.

Comment: @tchrist - I don't know why I interpreted this so differently. Seems reasonable now...